# Init object from its parent's Builder class in java

Tags: java

I have a parent class like :

```
public abstract class ParentObject {

    public abstract String[] fields();

    public abstract String tableName();

}
```

And a child class like this :

```
public class MyObject extends ParentObject {


    String id = "";
    String name = "";

    public MyObject(Map<String, Object> map){
        this.id = map.get("id").toString();
        this.name = map.get("name").toString();
    }


    @Override
    public String[] fields() {
        return new String[]{"id","name"};
    }

    @Override
    public String tableName() {
        return "testTable";
    }

}
```

I want to create a Builder Class in ParentObject to be able to init all the child classes like :

```
MyObject object = new MyObject.Builder().getById("objectId").build();
```

I tried using generics but i could not find what i was looking for i need a Builder class like :

```
public static class Builder{

    public Builder(){

    }

    public Builder getById(){
        //some server codes here
        return Builder.this;
    }

    public T build(){
        return new T(map);
    }
}
```

I need to know if i can use generics like this :

```
return new T();
```

If no, how can i do it ?

Comment: you can't. how are you going to know there will never be any other childclasses? neither should you. the parent should not even be aware of the child. if you are going to define the child in the parent, there is no need for the child at all. just put a builder in the child class

Comment: See [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) about generics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you need something like the following:

```
public <T extends ParentObject> T build(Class<T> targetClass) throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
    T t = targetClass.newInstance();
    t.tableName(); // can access the method
    return t;
}
```

You need to pass in the `targetClass` like `build(MyObject.class)`.